# Ways to improve performance for line-based conduits

Tags: haskell, io, conduit

I use haskell for line-based data processing, i.e. tasks where you can apply `sed`, `awk` and similar tools. As a trivial example, let's prepend `000` to every line from standard input.

I have three alternative ways to do the task:

1. Lazy IO with lazy `ByteString`s
2. Line-based conduit.
3. Chunk-based conduit with pure strict `ByteString` processing inside.

`example.hs`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import ClassyPrelude.Conduit
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B8
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BL8
import qualified Data.Conduit.Binary as CB

main = do
  [arg] <- getArgs
  case arg of

    "lazy" -> BL8.getContents >>= BL8.putStr . BL8.unlines . map ("000" ++) . BL8.lines

    "lines" -> runConduitRes $ stdinC .| CB.lines .|
      mapC ("000" ++) .| mapC (`snoc` 10) .| stdoutC

    "chunks" -> runConduitRes $ stdinC .| lineChunksC .|
      mapC (B8.unlines . (map ("000" ++)) . B8.lines) .| stdoutC


lineChunksC :: Monad m => Conduit ByteString m ByteString
lineChunksC = await >>= maybe (return ()) go
  where
  go acc = if
    | Just (_, 10) <- unsnoc acc -> yield acc >> lineChunksC
    | otherwise -> await >>= maybe (yield acc) (go' . breakAfterEOL)
    where
    go' (this, next) = let acc' = acc ++ this in if null next then go acc' else yield acc' >> go next

breakAfterEOL :: ByteString -> (ByteString, ByteString)
breakAfterEOL = uncurry (\x -> maybe (x, "") (first (snoc x)) . uncons) . break (== 10)
```

```
$ stack ghc --package={classy-prelude-conduit,conduit-extra} -- -O2 example.hs -o example
$ for cmd in lazy lines chunks; do echo $cmd; time -p seq 10000000 | ./example $cmd > /dev/null; echo; done
lazy
real 2.99
user 3.06
sys 0.07

lines
real 3.30
user 3.36
sys 0.06

chunks
real 1.83
user 1.95
sys 0.06
```

(The results are consistent across multiple runs, and also hold for lines with several numbers).

So `chunks` is 1.6x faster than `lines` which is a bit faster than `lazy`. This means that conduits can be faster than plain bytestrings, but the overhead of conduit pipes is too heavy when you split chunks into short lines.

What I don't like about `chunks` approach is that it mixes both conduit and pure worlds, and it makes it harder to use it for more complex tasks.

The question is, did I miss a simple and elegant solution which would allow me to write efficient code in same fashion as with `lines` approach?

EDIT1: Per @Michael's suggestion I joined two `mapC` into one `mapC (("000" ++). (`snoc`10))` in `lines` solution, to make number of pipes (`.|`) same between `lines` and `chunks`. This made it perform a bit better (down from 3.3s to 2.8s), but still significantly slower than `chunks`.

Also I tried older `Conduit.Binary.lines` which Michael suggested in comments, and it also improves performance a bit, by ~0.1s.

EDIT2: Fixed `lineChunksC` so it works with very small chunks, e.g.

```
> runConduitPure $ yield ("\nr\n\n"::ByteString) .| concatC .| mapC singleton .| lineChunksC .| sinkList 
["\n","r\n","\n"]
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `mapC (\`snoc\` 10)`?

Comment: @chepner 10 is Word8 value for `'\n'`, so it appends newline character back to each line.

Comment: This has a bug, for starters. Suppose I break the source up into one-byte bytestrings `stdinC' = (stdinC :: Source (ResourceT IO) B.ByteString)  .| concatC .| mapC B.singleton`  This doesn't affect the semantics of `stdinC` but it breaks this function, but not the conduit lines function.

Comment: When it is corrected, it will emerge that in gluing the one-byte bytestrings together into lines, your `chunks` function allocates as many intermediate bytestrings as there are bytes in the line. It is rational where you expect one or two chunks per line. This is fairly typical of course.

Comment: It occurs to me the old conduit `lines` had this property; see this patch https://github.com/snoyberg/conduit/pull/209 It might be that the old version was faster for inputs like yours, where we have a ton of one-chunk short lines.

Comment: @Michael it seems like the old `CB.lines` performs better for me (speeds the run by ~5%), but most of time is spent in conduit pipeline anyway (fuse, `>>=`).

Comment: @Michael I guess you mean the bug is in my `lineChunksC`? It's quite likely, I just wrote for the `chunks` solution and never tested on anything else.

Comment: Yes, if it is given the bytes in tiny chunks it exits after two lines.

Comment: The regular conduit function speeds up if you assimilate the maps writing  `mapC (("000" ++). (\`snoc\` 10))`  instead of  `mapC ("000" ++) .| mapC (\`snoc\` 10)`. This is done implicitly by the other.

Comment: There is a crude rule of course that more uses of  `.|` makes for a more complex program - unless they fuse away. Your `chunks` uses three, but your `lines` uses four. This has nothing to do with the lines function.

Comment: @Michael see my edit. Joining two `mapC` improves performance, but not drastically, so there is still serious performance loss with per-line conduit processing.

Comment: Until you correct the implementation of `lineChunksC` it will be impossible to bench this. Try it with, e.g. `yield ("\nr\n\n"::B.ByteString) =$= concatC =$= mapC B.singleton` instead of `stdinC`. This is essential to benchmarking.

Comment: @Michael I updated the answer with fixed version. It didn't change the timing at all (no surprise, as with normal stdin it's called only once every N kilobytes)

Comment: Right,  it is fast for some nice cases, since it uses `ByteString.lines` where possible - but as expected, if I feed it a file that is 10 million 't's with no linebreaks, it is much slower http://sprunge.us/APeK If I give the file in single byte chunks char by char, it doesn't complete after 5 minutes, since it is allocating 10M separate bytestrings, while the other is done in 5 sec. It is I think quadratic in the number of chunks per line. Here's my source http://sprunge.us/gVQG

Comment: @Michael thanks, it's a good example. Building strict bytestring from many pieces is gonna be slow.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that, for "lines", the `` mapC ("000" ++) .| mapC (`snoc` 10) `` part is doing a lot of work.

Concatenating several strict `ByteStrings` into another strict `ByteString` is expensive. Concatenating them into a lazy `ByteString` tends to be more efficient.

To avoid this cost, you can yield each part individually downstream as a strict `ByteString` (but be aware that then we aren't talking about "lines" anymore).

Alternatively, yield each transformed line as a lazy `ByteString` downstream.

---

> The question is, did I miss a simple and elegant solution which would
>   allow me to write efficient code in same fashion as with lines
>   approach?

Some streaming libraries have an interesting feature: you can delimit lines in the stream, and manipulate them, without the need to materialize entire lines in memory at any point.

Here I'm using the [*streaming*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming) and [*streaming-bytestring*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-bytestring-0.1.4.4) packages, because I'm more familiar with them.

In module [`Data.ByteString.Streaming.Char8`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-bytestring-0.1.4.4/docs/Data-ByteString-Streaming-Char8.html) of *streaming-bytestring*, we have the [`lines`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-bytestring-0.1.4.4/docs/Data-ByteString-Streaming-Char8.html#v:lines) function:

```
lines :: Monad m => ByteString m r -> Stream (ByteString m) m r
```

> lines turns a ByteString into a connected stream of ByteStrings at
>   divide at newline characters. The resulting strings do not contain
>   newlines. This is the genuinely streaming lines which only breaks
>   chunks, and thus never increases the use of memory.

The gist of it is that `ByteString m r` is *already* a streaming type! So this version of `lines` transforms a stream into a "stream of streams". And we can only reach the "next stream" (next line) by exhausting the "current stream" (current line).

Your "lines" example could be written as:

```
{-# language OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Control.Applicative ((*>))
import Streaming
import qualified Streaming.Prelude as S
import qualified Data.ByteString.Streaming.Char8 as Q

main :: IO ()
main = Q.stdout
     . Q.unlines
     . S.maps (\line -> "000" *> line)
     . Q.lines
     $ Q.stdin
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I should defnitely check `streaming`. But after adding your code into benchmark, results are on par with my "lines" solution (+/- 5%), so no immediate improvements in my case.